# Android autocompletetextview dropdown box's elements have a large font

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I would like to change the autocomplete dropdown boxes element size to something smaller.
Any change i do with textview.settextsize affects only the value in the fieldbox and not in the drop down box!

[image: Screeshot with shows the large font for drop down and the smaller for the listbox]

I am adding the list items dynamically and my adapter is set to the resource

```
adapterForFromAutoText.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

Should i add my own resource to customize the style of the font, if so does it matter that i use `adapterForFromAutoText.add(displayName);` to dynamically add data through the adapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the attribute `"android:textSize"` within your "`android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`"? You may want to try to change the textSize there.

You may also want to check out this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

Comment: Thank you .. the tutorial had the answer.

Comment: What was the answer? - the point of this forum is to help people. Not keep the answers to yourself.

Comment: @Mark I had the same issue and this answer was not helpful. My solution is that I copied simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml to my layout folder and changed the android:layout_height attribute.

Comment: @Bevor where is `simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml` located orignially?

Comment: @JuiCe It's in the layout directory of your android installation in the folder of the sdkversion you use. That means for example: 
`/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-7/data/res/layout/simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Use This Layout , It will change the autocomplete dropdown boxes element size to smaller

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aList);
```